# Create function that receives any function with specific amount of parameters

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Say I have several different gRPC servers, for example `x.Server`, `y.Server` and `z.Server`, and in order to spin them up, I have a lot of repeated code inside their main function, e.g.:

```golang
func main() {
    if err := config.EnsureArgLength(1); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }

    srv := &x.Server{}
    if err := srv.ReadServerConfig(os.Args[1]); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    if err := srv.RegisterListener(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    if err := srv.RegisterClients(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    proto.RegisterXServer(s, srv)

    if err := srv.Serve(s); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

I would love to refactor this main function to make it one or two lines long, something like the following:

```golang
func main() {
    srv := x.Server{}
    if err := srv.RegisterAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to serve: %s", err.Error())
    }
}
```

But each server will have an auto-generated function `proto.RegisterXServer` which is not part of `x.Server` struct, and I'm also not able to modify the file which contains it, since it is auto generated. How should I proceed?

Comment: You can't. The closest you could get is taking the function as an `interface{}` and then using runtime reflection, but you'd lose all type safety.

Comment: it is not great you have changed the question so much. My answer does not make sense at all. Adrian comment neither. You should have created a new question. I wonder who accepted this edit.

Answer (score 0):

in regards to op changes, which was radical,

I can suggest using a reducer pattern like this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fail(reduce(sayHello(), sayGoodbye))
}
func sayHello() func() error {
    return func() error { fmt.Println("Hello, playground"); return nil }
}
func sayGoodbye() error {
    fmt.Println("Goodbye from the playground")
    return nil
}
func reduce(h ...func() error) error {
    for _, hh := range h {
        if err := hh(); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func fail(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```